# Split a string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to split a string according to the next idea:

```js
const strin = 'test <br><span>test</span>  <div>aa</div>8'.split(/<\ *>/i)
console.log(strin)
```

So, the expected output is next:
`['test','<br>', '<span>test</span>', '<div>aa</div>', '8']`

Comment: There's nothing that matched `/<\ *>/` in the text

Comment: That will match `<>` with only spaces in it.

Comment: That seems like a strange requirement. Why not parse the string as HTML instead? For example `Array.from(new DOMParser().parseFromString("test <br><span>test</span>  <div>aa</div>8", "text/html").body.childNodes)` gets you an array of all six nodes (you’re missing the spaces between `</span>` and `<div>`).

Comment: Why are you using `split()` for this?

Comment: A classic [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Array.prototype.split is not a good solution to this problem due to how complicated it will be, so you need to look for a new approach such as @SebastianSimon's DOMParser idea

Comment: @Samathingamajig It’s not only “complicated”, it’s _impossible_. HTML isn’t a regular language; regular expressions, as the name suggests, only work for regular languages. You can use loops and other constructs outside of regular expressions, but this is akin to writing your own HTML parser, which is superfluous since `DOMParser` already exists.

Comment: @SebastianSimon, i want to group each html tag and after that to test with a regex f it is valid

Comment: Ah, I see, it’s related to your earlier question: [Test if string is a valid HTML code using javascript](/q/69799487/4642212). I’d still like to see a solid definition of “valid”.

Comment: @SebastianSimon, VALID = is a real Html tag that developers use(ex: `test` !== valid html, <div>test</div> === valid, <div>test<div> !== valid ). It is clear now?

Comment: @SebastianSimon, do you know a solution for that?

Comment: @Asking So you’re not actually asking about _HTML validity_ (in the sense of HTML specification conformity) at all; `test` clearly is a valid HTML fragment; your examples should have `<!DOCTYPE html>`, etc. to be considered _valid_. Do you want to check if a string is exlusively made up of elements, i.e. `"<span>A</span><div>B</div>"`, but not `"<span>A</span><div>B</div>C"`? What about whitespace between tags? What about nested tags? What result do you expect? Simply a boolean indicating if the string meets your requirements? Or do you want to filter out text nodes? [Edit] to clarify!

Comment: The validation in my situation means: 1 each string should be wrapped in a html tag 2. Are allowed the html that don’t have closing tag like <br>3. The whitespaces between tags are allowed 4.nested tags are allowed. If the string contains and element that is not allowed the function should return false if not returns true.

Comment: @SebastianSimon  could you please help?

Comment: So `const valid = !Array.from(new DOMParser().parseFromString("test <br><span>test</span>  <div>aa</div>8 <x></x><y>asd</y>", "text/html").body.childNodes).filter((node) => (node.nodeType !== Document.ELEMENT_NODE || node instanceof HTMLUnknownElement) && (node.nodeType !== Document.TEXT_NODE || node.textContent.trim())).length;` is probably a good start.

Comment: @SebastianSimon, very nice, but i tried to test `<br><span>test</span><div>aa<x>ss</x></div>` and it gives me true. Could you help please? It will help me a lot

Comment: @SebastianSimon, probably the issue is related with nested tags.

Answer (score 0):

As @sebastian-simon mentioned, "split" HTML with only regular expression is impossible. The best solution is use a real HTML parser (already shipped with your browser, if you are using Node.js, you can use [JSDOM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom)).

```js
var str = 'test <br><span>test</span> <fake></fake> <div><p>aa</p></div>8';
var container = document.createElement("div");
container.innerHTML = str; // use a HTML element to parse HTML

// If you need to work with nested tag, you should traverse childNodes and their childNodes by yourself

// childNodes included TextNode, children not.
// [...container.childNodes] convert container.childNodes to a normal array
// so we can .map over it
var elmList = [...container.childNodes];
var tags = elmList
  // if elm is a TextNode, elm.outerHTML is undefined
  // then we use elm.textContent instead
  .map(elm => elm.outerHTML ?? elm.textContent)
  .map(elm => elm.trim()) // remove whitespaces
  .filter(elm => elm); // remove empty items
console.log(tags)
```

Comment: i am not sure if i undertand regarding nested tags. Could you show please? Probably you mean this : <div>4<span>test</span></div>

Comment: Yes, "nested tags" means something like `<div>4<span>test</span></div>`, a HTML tag in another HTML tag.

Comment: how to purceed in this situation?

Comment: Recursive will do that, you start with `container`, check every childNodes of it. Then for each childNodes, check it's own childNodes, then do same thing to those "grandchildNodes"...

Comment: Could you show please?